# less-than operator doesn't work properly after few executions

Tags: c++, if-statement, boolean-operations

I'm a beginner to learning C++. Just today I tried to learn the boolean operator and `if-else` statement.

This is the code:

```
int main(){
    //if-else statement
    int a, b;
    bool result = (a < b);
    
    std::cout << "input number 1 : ";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "input number 2 : ";
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << result <<std::endl;
    if(result == true){
        std::cout << a << " is less than " << b << std::endl;
    }
    if(!(result == true)){
        std::cout << a << " is NOT less than " << b << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

These are the results after a few executions:

[image]

Initially the results were fine, but then after a couple times it went wrong.

Does anybody know what the cause of this is?

Comment: `result` is not a function. It's a variable holding uninitialized data of `a < b`. You may move that line before you want to use it.

Comment: `bool result = (a < b);` invokes undefined behavior. Neither `a` nor `b` have a determinate value at the time `result` is calculated. The value of `result` doesn't magically change later in the program as the values of `a` and `b` change. If you want what it seems you desire, a *lambda* may do it, or a macro (and *yuck*, btw, to the latter).

Comment: On a side note, `if (result == true)` --> `if (result)` and `if (!(result == true))` --> `if (!result)`.

Comment: Also, `if (c) { ... } if (!c) { ...)` --> `if (c) { ... } else { ... }`.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/6GnjxqEfe

Answer (score 7):

Your mistake is that you compare the two variables and save the `result` **before you assign any proper values** to these variables. In other words, you compare *uninitialized* variables `a` and `b` which have *undefined* values.

First, you do:

```
bool result = (a < b);
```

And then after you get the values:

```
std::cin >> a;
std::cin >> b;
```

You should do the following instead:

```
// ...
int a, b;
std::cout << "input number 1 : ";
std::cin >> a;
std::cout << "input number 2 : ";
std::cin >> b;

bool result = a < b; // <-- move this down here!
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You expect `result` to be evaluate `a == b` when you use it later. Instead `bool result = (a < b);` initializes `result` with `(a < b)` once and its value does not change afterwards. As neither `a` nor `b` are initialized when you declare `result` your code has undefined behavior.

You can make `result` a function object to make it work as you expected by using a lambda expression. However, to call it you'll have to add `()`:

```
int main(){
    //if-else statement
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    auto result = [&](){ return a < b; };

    std::cout << "input number 1 : ";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "input number 2 : ";
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << result() <<std::endl;
    if(result()) {
        std::cout << a << " is less than " << b << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << a << " is NOT less than " << b << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You should always initialize variables. Using the value of uninitialized variables is undefined behavior and can happen easily (as in your code) when you do not initialize variables. Instead of `if (condition) {} if (!condition){}` you can use `if (condition) {} else {}`. Instead of `if (result() == true)` you can write `if (result())`. And `return 0;` is implicit in `main`, you need not write it.

Comment: Lambdas might be a bit early for the OP, though.

Comment: IMO feeding lambda to a newbie is not good idea.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I tend to disagree. If it helps them to write code that feels naturally for them, why not? I tried to do my best to explain whats wrong with their code, though I admit feeding them with the lambda expression without more info on lambdas is suboptimal

Answer (score 1):

You overall code as it should be.

Explanations in the comments:

```
int main() {
  //if-else statement
  int a, b;

  std::cout << "input number 1 : ";
  std::cin >> a;
  std::cout << "input number 2 : ";
  std::cin >> b;

  bool result = (a < b);   // put this here, because now a and b have
                           // determined values

  std::cout << std::boolalpha << result << std::endl;

  if (result) {            // or simple if (a < b) and drop result alltogether
    std::cout << a << " is less than " << b << std::endl;
  }
  else  {                  // no need for testing the opposite of result
    std::cout << a << " is NOT less than " << b << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```